# How to prevent side area clickable of UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem

`[image: Arrow display area which i want to prevent to click]

Whenever i click on this area , action also perform on this.

Comment: What Action performed when you click on this area Done or Cancel?

Comment: if i click near to done then done action perform and if i click near to cancel then perform cancel action.

Comment: [UIBarButtonItems much larger click area than required](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2271945/593709)

Comment: You can also check out this solution. Worked well in my case. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16557050/720175

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry about this behavior, iOS auto tapp near element if there is not other element.

If you really want to prevent to click except button, then you have to put Element on unused area which should be inherited from `UIControl` or able to get `UserInteraction`.

Answer (score 1):

I got solution. I put one UIButton between these two UIBarButtonItem and make it custom and nil it's selector.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can try this: (Swift version)

```
    let btnName = UIButton()
    btnName.setImage(UIImage(named: "settings_filled_25"), forState: .Normal)
    btnName.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
    btnName.addTarget(self, action: Selector("toggleRight"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    var rightView = UIView()
    rightView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
    rightView.addSubview(btnName)

    let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem()
    rightBarButton.customView = rightView
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```