# Modified navigationbar causes issues on button item

Tags: ios, objective-c

In our project we wanted to change the size of navigationbar. Have achieved it with

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (customNav)
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    return CGSizeMake(self.superview.bounds.size.width, 55.0f);
}
@end
```

But the problem here is.. as you would see **go** button is little down from screen edge. But I wanted it to be in ultimate corner of screen. I use `backgroundColor:`, `setTitle:forState:`methods for constructing look of go button.  also back button to be vertically middle. How can I achieve that. Tried Using `edgeInsets:` but no hope.

[image]

Edit: Go button height is 10px less than barheight.

if I give equal height. Below is the result

[image]

Comment: Did you increase the height for button?

Comment: button size is 10 px less than bar height now.. If i make it equal 5px of Go button color coming into white space

Comment: wait let me try this.

Comment: @user3182143 Check my edit

Comment: Did you set the set button and height programmatically?

Comment: Whole button added programatically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96328/discussion-between-user3182143-and-idev).

Comment: Did you get solution or not?

Comment: I didt get the solution yet

Comment: Did you try the below answer?

Comment: HOpe this would work

Comment: @user3182143   thanks.. Gave upvote

Answer (score 1):

in somewhat I have tried your coding.Check that

```
UIButton *goBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
goBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 63, 80);
goBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
UIView *goButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 63, 50)];
NSLog(@"goButtonView bounds are - %@", NSStringFromCGRect([goButtonView bounds]));
goButtonView.bounds = CGRectOffset(goButtonView.bounds, -17, 0);
NSLog(@"goButtonView bounds are - %@", NSStringFromCGRect([goButtonView bounds]));
[goButtonView addSubview:goBtn];
UIBarButtonItem *goButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:goButtonView];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = goButton;
```

Below the references

[Issue with button on the left side of the uinavigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338681/issue-with-button-on-the-left-side-of-the-uinavigation-bar)

[UINavigationBar UIBarButtonItems much larger click area than required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271945/uinavigationbar-uibarbuttonitems-much-larger-click-area-than-required)